# How do I make a hashmap out of arraylist where one column with repeat values are the keys and corresponding lines as values

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I know this a basic question but for some reason I haven't been able to resolve this issue in java although I have been trying and (looking for solutions) for the past few days...
I have a tab separated file(large file more than 8000 lines) with multiple columns(few of these columns have spaces and ":" between their elements).I have read this file and stored it an ArrayList by reading the file line by line

```
String filepath = "/home/path/T1.csv"; 
ArrayList<String[]> listOfLines = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> column8 = new ArrayList <>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filepath)) ;

while(scan.hasNextLine())
{String line = scan.nextLine();listOfLines.add(line.split("\\t+"));column8.add(line.split("\\t+"));}
```

In column 8 I have there repeating values of "Yes", "NO" and "Maybe" (few in uppercase and few in lower case).I have to create a HashMap (suggestions for alternative methods appreciated) where the values of this column are keys and and the whole line corresponding to this key is the value i.e.one key multiple values so that the end result is that lines are bundled based on the common entries "yes,no and maybe" of column 8.

The input file has lines in this format and the number of columns (separated by tab) are exceeding more than 8 in some places

```
 1.456  Fri Jun 01 16:38:01 IST 2018    APB electron microscopy P5299   raw processed   no   
Incorrect Term.     {"electron microscopy"}
1.5457  Fri Jun 01 12:16:03 IST 2018    JIAU    Crystallography P1189   raw raw yes Term 
too broad.  {"Rietveld refinements"}
1.557   Fri Jun 01 12:16:03 IST 2018    JAU  positron collider  P72411  processed   processed   maybe
1.567   Fri Jun 01 12:16:04 IST 2018    JAU  positron collider  P72411  processed   processed   maybe
```

the result I want is bundling the lines based on the value of column 8 something like this

```
yes bundle
1.5457  Fri Jun 01 12:16:03 IST 2018    JIAU    Crystallography P1189   raw raw yes Term 
too broad.  {"Rietveld refinements"}

no bundle
1.456   Fri Jun 01 16:38:01 IST 2018    APB electron microscopy P5299   raw processed   no   
Incorrect Term.     {"electron microscopy"}
maybe bundle
1.557   Fri Jun 01 12:16:03 IST 2018    JAU  positron collider  P72411  processed   processed   maybe
1.567   Fri Jun 01 12:16:04 IST 2018    JAU  positron collider  P72411  processed   processed   maybe
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you please edit your question and add some example about the input file, and your expected output? Thanks

Comment: If I get you right, then you wanted probably to declare a variable `column8` instead of `column6`. In you last line you are using `column8`.

Comment: one option is to create `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>`, then populate it by checking each string array that you get out of the line for the value of particular column (which is the key)

Comment: For the record: dont write your own CSV parser. Unless you are in total control of the incoming files, it will break. CSV is harder than it sounds. Consider using a library/parser that does that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// toLowerCase for case insensitive comparison of column 8
listOfLines.forEach(x -> x[7] = x[7].toLowerCase(Locale.US));
Map<String, List<String[]>> map = listOfLines.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[7]));
```

This produces a `Map<String, List<String[]>>`. If you want a `Map<String, List<String>>`, you can easily concatenate the strings in each string array and put them in a new map.